# Change Ruby version used in Sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

How do you change the Ruby version Sublime uses while testing.  It is currently using 1.8, but I want it to use 1.9.3 which is set to my default in RVM.  When I type which ruby, I get 1.9.3, but Sublime is not using it.

Comment: This gist might provide you with the answers you need:

https://gist.github.com/pmarreck/2367908

Answer (score 1):

From this gist: https://gist.github.com/fny/8008316

Include the configuration below in the appropriate file as listed here:

- OS X ST2: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build
- OS X ST3: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Ruby.sublime-build
- Linux ST2: ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build
- Linux ST3: ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Ruby.sublime-build

  {
    "working_dir": "${project_path}",
    "env": {
      "PATH": "${HOME}/.rvm/bin:${PATH}"
     },
    "cmd": [
      "rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"
    ],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
  }